# How to use keyref on nested element tag

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

What I want to validate:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <A>
      <a id="ID-1"/>
      <a id="ID-2"/>
    </A>
    <BBB>
      <b>
        <bb>
            <bbb idref="ID-1"></bbb>
        </bb>
      </b>
    </BBB>
</root>
```

Here is my `.xsd` file:

```
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="A" type="myA"/>
        <xsd:element name="BBB" type="myBBB"/>
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="myId">
      <xsd:selector xpath="./A/a"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:keyref name="myIdref" refer="myId">
      <xsd:selector xpath="./BBB/b/bb/bbb"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="@idref"/>
    </xsd:keyref>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="myA">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="a">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="myBBB">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="b">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:all>
              <xsd:element name="bb">
                  <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="bbb">
                              <xsd:complexType>
                                  <xsd:simpleContent>
                                      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                          <xsd:attribute name="idref" type="xsd:ID"></xsd:attribute>
                                      </xsd:extension>
                                  </xsd:simpleContent>
                              </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                      </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
          </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

However I am getting:

> element bbb: Schemas validity error : Element 'bbb', attribute 'idref':
>   Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.

I tried using `xsd:NCName` but that didn't change anything. If I use `ID-3` which is not yet defined, I get

> No match found for key-sequence ['ID-3'] of keyref 'myIdref'.

I want to reference the `id` of the A element with `idref` of the bbb element. Is my `xPath` wrong?
Should I not use `xsd:ID` for `keyRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your problem is that you want the `bbb`'s element attribute type to be `xsd:IDREF` rather than `xsd:ID`. Then it would correspond with your `xsd:ID` definition:

```
<xsd:attribute name="idref" type="xsd:IDREF"></xsd:attribute>
```

A minor fix to add would be adding a `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute to the

```
...
<xsd:complexType name="myA">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    ...
```

So, the whole XSD could be

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="A" type="myA"/>
        <xsd:element name="BBB" type="myBBB"/>
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="myId">
      <xsd:selector xpath="./A/a"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:keyref name="myIdref" refer="myId">
      <xsd:selector xpath="./BBB/b/bb/bbb"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="@idref"/>
    </xsd:keyref>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="myA">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="a">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="myBBB">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="b">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:all>
              <xsd:element name="bb">
                  <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="bbb">
                              <xsd:complexType>
                                  <xsd:simpleContent>
                                      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                          <xsd:attribute name="idref" type="xsd:IDREF"></xsd:attribute>
                                      </xsd:extension>
                                  </xsd:simpleContent>
                              </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                      </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
          </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now your XSD should validate your XML.
To make this work, you don't even need the

```
<xsd:key name="myId">
  <xsd:selector xpath="./A/a"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
</xsd:key>

<xsd:keyref name="myIdref" refer="myId">
  <xsd:selector xpath="./BBB/b/bb/bbb"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@idref"/>
</xsd:keyref>
```

because this functionality is implied in the `xsd:ID`/`xsd:IDREF` code. `xs:keyref` is more flexible, but in your example, it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing some pretty poor diagnostics from your schema processor: what kind of software outputs a misspelt message like "or something strange happend"?

Here's the output from Saxon:

```
Processing file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml
Validation error on line 4 column 19 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <A>: The content model does not allow element <Q{}a> to
  appear more than once. 
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
Validation error on line 4 column 19 of test.xml:
  The field in constraint {myId} has no value
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-identity-constraint clause 4.2.1
Validation error on line 9 column 27 of test.xml:
  XQDY0027: ID value 'ID-1' is not unique
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-id clause 2
```

Let's go through these.

The first one is easily fixed by adding maxOccurs="unbounded" in type `myA`.

When we fix this, the second error goes away: I think Saxon's evaluation of the XPath expression in the selector was making assumptions that the data would be valid, and it found nothing because this assumption wasn't true.

The third error is because you declared `bbb/@idref` as an xs:ID. If you change it to say xs:NCName, the error goes away.

You need to decide whether you want to do the referential integrity checking using the ID/IDREF mechanism or the key/keyref mechanism. It makes no sense to use both.

Comment: I am using command line XML tool `xmllint` for validation. I copied the output from my terminal and didn't even notice the misspelled word, but it is indeed there.